# Assigning a string to a structure in C w/ Segemntation fault

Tags: c, string, structure

Currently, I try to solve an excercise in an exam for preparation. After researching here, I changed the structure definition of

```
char nr[10];
char name[25];
```

to

```
char *nr;
char *name;
```

to pass a string (a pointer to a string) into the structure (see the whole code below).

When I execute the code with Netbeans 8.2 and Cygwin GCC 7.4.0 I got a runtime error. Sometimes the code runs endlessly w/o termination, sometimes I got a segmentation error. After debugging, the error occurs once the compiler tries to execute

```
new->item->nr = orderno;
```

What I realized by another excercise w/ bubble sort where you've a swap function. I'm used to swap the referenced values like this:

```
void swap(int *px, int *py) {
  int temp = *px;
  *px = *py;
  *py = temp;
}
```

What I'd like to do is swapping by using the addresses like this:

```
void swap(int *px, int *py) {
  int *temp = px;
  px = py;
  py = temp;
}
```

Netbeans shows the same behavior by running endlessly w/o termination either the swap function or the code I'm creating ths topic for. Does anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct litem_t {
    char *nr;   // was char nr[10];
    char *name; // was char name[25];
    float price;
    int cnt;
    float sum;
} litem;
typedef struct llist_t {
    struct litem_t *item;
    struct llist_t *next;
} llist;

llist* addItem(llist *alist, char *orderno, char *name, float price, int count, float sum);
void dumpList(llist *alist);

void L_3_a_KL_17(int argc, char **argv) {
    llist *alist;
    alist = addItem(NULL, "AT 1001 C", "Pear jPhone Quad 64GB", 499.00, 1, 499.00);
    alist = addItem(alist, "ZT 1012 D", "Pear jPhone Octa 128GB", 799.00, 1, 799.00);
    
    dumpList(alist);
}

llist* addItem(llist *alist, char *orderno, char *name, float price, int count, float sum) {
    llist *new = (llist *)malloc(sizeof(llist));
    if(new == NULL)
        return NULL;
    new->item->nr = orderno; // runtime error here
    new->item->name = name;
    new->item->price = price;
    new->item->cnt = count;
    new->item->sum = sum;
    new->next = alist;
    return new;
}

void dumpList(llist *alist) {
    llist *temp;
    int j = 1;
    while(alist != NULL) {
        printf("\n%d. Article:\nNumber:\t%s\nName:\t%s\nPrice:\t%.2f\nCnt:\t%d\nSum:\t%.2f",                                     
            j, alist->item->nr, alist->item->name, alist->item->price, alist->item->cnt,
            alist->item->summe);
        temp = alist;
        alist = alist->next;
        free(temp);
        j++;
    }
}
```

Basically, the code should read articles, store them sequentially in a concatenated list and print them on the screen afterwards. The sequence of the articles doesn't matter.

Thanks for any help.

KR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your list source there are a few mistakes

With

```
ptr->item->nr = orderno;
```

you copy the pointer to a string to the pointer in the struct. This works only if the string is already stored on the heap and you pass the pointer as parameter in the function call.

In your example you copy the string address only. If that string is not longer available if the function is returned, the pointer does not point to the expected string. You should copy the strings to buffers as you have defined them in your first version or make sure that the strings exists as long as the pointer inside the data struct has its value.

The second problem is that you allocate memory for the list entry but not for the item it-self. That causes the error your mentioned. The list entry contains only a pointer to the item! So you have to allocate memory for the item as well. If this fails you have to error handle the problem that you have successfully created a list element but not the data item.

For answering the question in your comment please let me go into some details

You define a struct type for data

```
typedef struct litem_t {
    char nr[10];   // was char nr[10];
    char name[25]; // was char name[25];
    float price;
    int cnt;
    float sum;
} litem;
```

and a struct with pointers to chain the items:

```
typedef struct llist_t {
    struct litem_t *item;
    struct llist_t *next;
} llist;
```

Please look at this picture. You can see that you need to create for both structs an instance for each new data

```
   Chained Instances               data instances 
     of type llist                   of type litem
     
     Size of each                    Size of each element 
     instance is 8 byte              is 47 byte
         
    [alist]
     |
     |                                 
     '--> +--------+                   last created objects  
          | item --|--------------->  +-----------+               
          | next --|---.              | nr[10]    |   10 byte
          +--------+   |              | name[25]  |   25 byte 
                       |              | price     |    4 byte     
     .-----------------'              | cnt       |    4 byte   
     |                                | sum       |    4 byte     
     |                                +-----------+
     '--> +--------+     
          | item --|--------------->  +-----------+                        
          | next --|---.              | nr[10]    |               
          +--------+   |              | name[25]  |                 
                       |              | price     |                 
     .-----------------'              | cnt       |                 
     |                                | sum       |          
     |                                +-----------+           
     '--> +--------+                                         
          | item --|---------------> +-----------+          
          | next = NULL              | nr[10]    |                    
          +--------+                 | name[25]  |                     
                                     | price     |           
                                     | cnt       |           
                                     | sum       |           
                                     +-----------+           
                                     First created objects
```

The picture show that you first need to allocate memory for the llist item. Than the pointer "item" exists and you can allocate memory for the data item. Both items have to be freed separately, for example like this.

```
llist * next;
if (alist)
{
    do
    {
        next = alist->next;  // temp. copy because pointer will be deleted
        if (alist->item) free(alist->item);  // free memory for litem
        free (alist);                        // free memory for llist
        alist = next;                        // set alist to next item  
    } while (alist != NULL)                  /7 very first entry has no "next"  
}
```

Better would be create a function which frees a single item and correct the "next" pointer of the previous item. With this you could remove an item of the list. Such is IMHO one reason for using a chained list.

Code (without free)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct litem_t {
    char nr[10];   // was char nr[10];
    char name[25]; // was char name[25];
    float price;
    int cnt;
    float sum;
} litem;
typedef struct llist_t {
    struct litem_t *item;
    struct llist_t *next;
} llist;

llist* addItem(llist *alist, char const *orderno, char const *name, float price, int count, float sum);
void dumpList(llist *alist);

void L_3_a_KL_17(int argc, char **argv) {
    llist *alist;
    alist = addItem(NULL, "AT 1001 C", "Pear jPhone Quad 64GB", 499.00, 1, 499.00);
    alist = addItem(alist, "ZT 1012 D", "Pear jPhone Octa 128GB", 799.00, 1, 799.00);
    
    dumpList(alist);
}

llist* addItem(llist *alist, char const *orderno, char const *name, float price, int count, float sum) {
    // Alloccate space for new list entry 
    llist *newlistentry_ptr = (llist *)malloc(sizeof(llist));
    if(newlistentry_ptr == NULL)
        return NULL;
    
    // Alloc space for new data item 
    newlistentry_ptr->item = (litem *)malloc(sizeof(litem));   
    if(newlistentry_ptr->item == NULL) {
        // add here some error handling
        // caller will not expect that item is NULL
        // maybe free newlistentry_ptr for error detection
        newlistentry_ptr->next = alist;
        return newlistentry_ptr;
    }

    // Copy strings into a buffer where they are retained
    strncpy (newlistentry_ptr->item->nr, orderno, sizeof(newlistentry_ptr->item->nr)); 
    strncpy (newlistentry_ptr->item->name, name, sizeof(newlistentry_ptr->item->name));
    newlistentry_ptr->item->price = price;
    newlistentry_ptr->item->cnt = count;
    newlistentry_ptr->item->sum = sum;
    newlistentry_ptr->next = alist;
    return newlistentry_ptr;
}

void dumpList(llist *alist) {
    llist *temp;
    int j = 1;
    while(alist != NULL) {
        printf("\n%d. Article:\nNumber:\t%s\nName:\t%s\nPrice:\t%.2f\nCnt:\t%d\nSum:\t%.2f",                                     
            j, alist->item->nr, alist->item->name, alist->item->price, alist->item->cnt,
            alist->item->sum);
        temp = alist;
        alist = alist->next;
        free(temp);
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I read through your explanation, everything is clear to me, thanks for that, except one last thing: Why do I've to allocate space for litem as well? I thought, it'd be done when I allocate space for llist. Is it because of the pointer to a structer? I never used it this way before, that's why I'm asking. And based on that, should I also free both elements like `temp->item = alist->item; temp = alist; alist = alist->next; free(temp->list); free(temp);`? I did it on purpose and Netbeans doesn't throw any dumps.

Comment: You need to allocate both structures and therefore must also free both. I added some details in the answer - easier as here. Hope that helps.

Comment: Indeed, it's easier in the answer, but for me it's fine to say thank you in here. I understood everything and a little progress everyday is good progress.

Comment: String literals have static storage duration no matter where they appear.  That means that no, their lifetimes do not end when the (a) function in which they appear terminates its execution.

Comment: @John: You are right. This was not correct. But this works only as long as they are given as in the example. If the strings are read e.g. by in scanf and then given to the function the questions come back. To copy a pointer to an object the function can't expect to be static seems me to be not a good idea.

Comment: @ThomasKintzel, well yes, if you stipulate that the data are stored in an automatic object belonging to the current execution of the function then you can trivially conclude that its lifetime ends when the function execution terminates.  But (1) that was not the OP's case, so your answer was misleading in that regard, and (2) it is not necessarily characteristic of options that do not rely on string literals, either.  Indeed, your answer still isn't right in that regard.  Suppose the string were an automatic object belonging to `main()`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
void swap(int **px, int **py) {
  int *temp = *px;
  *px = *py;
  *py = temp;
}
...
int *p1, *p2;
...
swap(&p1, &p2);
```

This does not do anything useful:

```
void swap(int *px, int *py) {
  int *temp = px;
  px = py;
  py = temp;
}
```

just as this does not do anything useful:

```
void swap(int x, int x) {
  int temp = x;
  x = y;
  y = temp;
}
```

Comment: Why does the second block doesn't do anything useful? I debugged the code and it runs fine. I mean, it should swap the addresses instead of the values itself. Only when I run the code normally, Netbeans seems to be unresponsive when executing this function. Sure the last block doesn't do anyting usefule. It needs an integer as a return value and the return statement as well. Afterwards, it should do the same as the block above.

Comment: @xp10r3r the second bloc and the third bloc do roughly the same thing, they swap the parameters, but as they are local variables, nothing is going to happen outside the function.

Comment: @xp10r3r if you want an answer, you need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68411901/edit) the questrion and show a [MCVE].

Comment: I created a new answer as it differs from the former question. I posted a total bubble sort example where the swap function could be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *px, int *py) {
    int *temp = px;
    px = py;
    py = temp;
}

void bsort(int *v, int n) {
    typedef char boolean;
    boolean switch;
    const boolean
        FALSE = 0,
        TRUE = 1;
    do {
        switch = FALSE;
        for(int *i = v; i-v < n; i++)
            if(*i > *(i+1)) {
                swap(i, i+1)
                switch = TRUE;
            }
    } while(switch);
}

void main(void) {
    int
        v[] = {42, 51, 13, 48, 92, 16, 9, 68},
        n = (int)sizeof(v)/(int)sizeof(int);
    bsort(v, n-1);

    for(int *i = v; i-v < n; i++)
        printf("%d "; *i);
}
```

The swap function should switch the addresses which's working fine when I run in debug mode. Is it the same issue when leaving the function the pointer is beeing destroyed and the reference is lost? I thought as a pointer is only a reference, it should be changed within the swap function anyway. Do you get my point?

If it's the same issue as the former question, static should solve it, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

*Note: You ask a 2nd question. It seems that stackoverflow does not work like this. If it is not clear already you should ask your new questions as new topic.*

What do you want to swap? I guess you want to swap the values.

In this case the call and the function signature is correct but not the swap implementation. You swap the pointers inside swap() but this does not effect i or i+1 or the data the pointers point to.

You should dereference the pointers then you swap the data

```
// px points to data cell 1 (as i)
// py pounts to data cell 2 (as i+1)
void swap (int * px, int * py)
{
  int temp = *px;  // copy data cell 1 to temp
  *px = *py;       // copy data cell 2 to data cell 1
  *py = temp;      // copy temp to data cell 2
}
```

This actual exchanges data *i and *(i+1)